# PHP XML - bad value returning

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

currently I'm working on one e-commerce project. I have XML full of products that I need to implement on the e-shop.

The problem is that my XML parser returns bad values, example: I have float 32 000, 00 and it parse only 32 to my php variable. The number that I'm parsing is somehow divided by thousand and I don't know why. Exactly same code just with XML file that has 32 000 works fine. Are they any convert setting that I need to set while initializing SimpleXML object?

Thanks for help.

Comment: this looks like a string that has `32 000, 00`  or `32` a `space` and a bunch of  `0` values which when PHP converts that to an INT or FLOAT turns into 32.   see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php  `$foo = 5 * "10 Little Piggies"; // $foo is integer (50)`  or `$foo = 5 * 10` after casting `"10 Little Piggies"` to an INT.  Same rule applies here.  you can test this [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ca759b9b06523301622f80dbf36066ce728c2ab)

Comment: Ok, thank you. But, I have numbers like 32 290,00 too and still its turning in 32.

Comment: See my answer!  That should take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at this

> I have float 32 000, 00 and it parse

No you have a string of `"32 000, 00"`.  So if we look at how PHP does type juggling

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

We see a few examples like this:

```
$foo = 5 * "10 Little Piggies"; // $foo is integer (50)
```

So the value of these 2 multiplied is `50` or `5*10` the ten is parsed from `"10 Little Piggies"`.  PHP will apply the same rules to what you have above which results in `32`.  Because it's a string with those `spaces` PHP will do it almost exactly the same way as above.

You can easily test this:

```
echo floatval('32 000, 00');
```

Output

```
32
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ca759b9b06523301622f80dbf36066ce728c2ab)

You may have to manually convert that to what it should be.  One easy thing to do is just remove the spaces:

```
  echo floatval(str_replace([' ',','], ['','.'], '32 000, 00'));
  #output 32000
  echo floatval(str_replace([' ',','], ['','.'], '32 290,01'));
  #output 32290.01
```

If I remember right some countries use the `,` as the `.` for decimal seperator.  But I had to replace the `,` with `.` to get them to work...  There may be some edge cases where this won't work, but without a bigger sample of data I can't say for sure.

Where or why those spaces are in there, I have no idea.  It would be better to remove them from the XML entirely, but that may not be possible.

Without some actual code in the question, that's the best I can do.

Cheers!

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.